# In Excel 2010, is it possible to desc order series on chart without changing the order of source data table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a source table that looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

What i'd like to do is, for each period, create a separate column chart that displays Items by their values in desc order. There will be 5 charts in all.

Currently I'm going the "stupid" way - copy and paste the values of each period into a new table, sort the values, and then create charts out of the new tables. However, I'm wondering if there is a "smart" way to achieve this without the need to change source table at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hub/2010/02/02/excelling-at-excel-how-to-quickly-flip-a-chart/)

Basically you need to enter that specific axis' options and check "reverse order".

Comment: thanks for the reply. However, I don't think this works for my case. Basically I'm not trying to reverse the order (the values have no order under each Period column). I'm trying to see it it's possible to order the values on the chart, without having to order the values in source table.

Comment: I see. Maybe named formulas might help: https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50fx/home/sort-the-data-on-the-excel-chart

Comment: thank you! After testing, I think named formula is the right direction to go.